# XML to Java code in Android

Tags: java, android

what i want to do converting xml to android code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/connectBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Connect" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/space"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/disconnectBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Disconnect" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <Button 
           android:id="@+id/btn1" 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="@string/btn1_txt" />

        <Button 
           android:id="@+id/btn2" 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="@string/btn2_txt" />

         <Button 
           android:id="@+id/btn3" 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="@string/btn3_txt" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Above code needed to convert to java code.

To do that, i need to create multiple linear layout in java. Is that the correct way? If not what is the correct way?

Comment: you want this android layout as java layout?

Comment: i want to write this xml in java code

Comment: Please do search how to dynamically create android layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inflate its views by doing:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(...);
```

Alternatively, you can simply create a view like

```
final LinearLayout l = [...]
//add stuff
l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
//etc...
```